# Why does HashSet return -1 for getExactSizeIfKnown

Tags: java, spliterator

I am trying to understand the features of SplitIterator and came across the below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> l = new HashSet();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3);
    Spliterator<Integer> s= (Spliterator<Integer>) l.spliterator();
Spliterator<Integer> s1=s.trySplit();
while(s1.tryAdvance(n -> {System.out.print(n+" ");System.out.println("estimateSize "+s.estimateSize()+" getexactsizeifknown "+s.getExactSizeIfKnown());}));
```

Why does the method `getexactsizeifknown` return `-1` for `HashSet`?

For other collections it returns the same output as the `estimateSIze()`

Comment: Well, the exact size might not be known.

Comment: Unrelated, but assign `new HashSet<>()` to `l` so you don't need to cast the spliterator.

Comment: @AndyTurner You don't need to cast the spliterator, with or without a raw type. The raw type should be fixed as well, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#getExactSizeIfKnown--) describes why:

> Convenience method that returns estimateSize() if this Spliterator is SIZED, else -1.

So, your spliterator isn't SIZED.

Comment: how do I size my isplitterator?

Comment: The **initial** iterator from the HashSet **is** sized, in line with the JavaDoc. After you do `trySplit`, it no longer is.